# Multi-monitor Screenshots only 2 monitors in C++ with WinApi

Tags: c++, winapi, screenshot

I've a function to take a screenshot on windows platforms with the WinApi and C++. It works perfectly with one and two monitors but when I run it on a machine with 3 monitors or more it only takes the picture of two monitors.

I think my poblem is that the content of the monitor to the left of the "main" monitor gets cut of. Sadly I have no idea how to fix it or what I am doing wrong.

I have read about BitBlt & StretchBlt so I tryed it with them but no success.

This it's what I'm doing:

```
// Get the system metrics
const int width = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN);
const int height = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN);
```

The width & height gets calculated perfectly for all monitors.

```
// Create a normal DC and a memory DC for the entire screen. The normal DC provides a "snapshot" of the screen contents.
// The memory DC keeps a copy of this "snapshot" in the associated bitmap.
const HDC hdcScr = CreateDCW(TEXT("DISPLAY"), NULL, NULL, NULL);
const HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcScr);



if (!StretchBlt(hdcMem, 0, 0, width, height, hdcScr, 0, 0, width, height, SRCCOPY)) {
    return;
}


// Create a compatible bitmap for hdcScreen.
const HBITMAP hbmScr = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcScr, width, height);
if (hbmScr == 0) {
    return;
}

if (!BitBlt(hdcMem, 0, 0, width, height, hdcScr, 0, 0, SRCCOPY)) {
    return;
}



// Select the bitmaps into the compatible DC.
if (!SelectObject(hdcMem, hbmScr)) {
    DeleteDC(hdcScr);
    DeleteDC(hdcMem);
    DeleteObject(hbmScr);
    return;
}

// Copy color data for the entire display into a bitmap that is selected into a compatible DC.
if (!StretchBlt(hdcMem, 0, 0, width, height, hdcScr, 0, 0, width, height, SRCCOPY)) {
    DeleteDC(hdcScr);
    DeleteDC(hdcMem);
    DeleteObject(hbmScr);
    return;
}

BITMAP bmp;

// Retrieve the bitmap's color format, width, and height.
if (!GetObject(hbmScr, sizeof(BITMAP), reinterpret_cast<LPSTR>(&bmp))) {
    DeleteDC(hdcScr);
    DeleteDC(hdcMem);
    DeleteObject(hbmScr);
    return;
}


// Convert the color format to a count of bits.
unsigned short cClrBits = bmp.bmPlanes * bmp.bmBitsPixel;
if (cClrBits == 1) {
    cClrBits = 1;
}
else if (cClrBits <= 4) {
    cClrBits = 4;
}
else if (cClrBits <= 8) {
    cClrBits = 8;
}
else if (cClrBits <= 16) {
    cClrBits = 16;
}
else if (cClrBits <= 24) {
    cClrBits = 24;
}
else {
    cClrBits = 32;
}


PBITMAPINFO pbmi;

// Allocate memory for the BITMAPINFO structure. (This structure contains a BITMAPINFOHEADER structure and an array of RGBQUAD data structures.)
if (cClrBits != 24) {
    pbmi = static_cast<PBITMAPINFO>(LocalAlloc(LPTR, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + sizeof(RGBQUAD) * (1 << cClrBits)));
}
else { // There is no RGBQUAD array for the 24-bit-per-pixel format.
    pbmi = static_cast<PBITMAPINFO>(LocalAlloc(LPTR, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER)));
}

// Initialize the fields in the BITMAPINFO structure.
pbmi->bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
pbmi->bmiHeader.biWidth = bmp.bmWidth;
pbmi->bmiHeader.biHeight = bmp.bmHeight;
pbmi->bmiHeader.biPlanes = bmp.bmPlanes;
pbmi->bmiHeader.biBitCount = bmp.bmBitsPixel;

if (cClrBits < 24) {
    pbmi->bmiHeader.biClrUsed = (1 << cClrBits);
}

// If the bitmap is not compressed, set the BI_RGB flag.
pbmi->bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;

// Compute the number of bytes in the array of color indices and store the result in biSizeImage.
pbmi->bmiHeader.biSizeImage = (pbmi->bmiHeader.biWidth + 7) / 8 * pbmi->bmiHeader.biHeight * cClrBits;

// Set biClrImportant to 0, indicating that all of the device colors are important.
pbmi->bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 0;


const PBITMAPINFOHEADER pbih = reinterpret_cast<PBITMAPINFOHEADER>(pbmi);              // bitmap info-header
const LPBYTE lpBits = static_cast<LPBYTE>(GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED, pbih->biSizeImage)); // memory pointer

if (!lpBits) {
    DeleteDC(hdcScr);
    DeleteDC(hdcMem);
    LocalFree(pbmi);
    GlobalFree(lpBits);
    DeleteObject(hbmScr);
    return;
}

// Retrieve the color table (RGBQUAD array) and the bits (array of palette indices) from the DIB.
if (!GetDIBits(hdcMem, hbmScr, 0, pbih->biHeight, lpBits, pbmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS)) {
    DeleteDC(hdcScr);
    DeleteDC(hdcMem);
    LocalFree(pbmi);
    GlobalFree(lpBits);
    DeleteObject(hbmScr);
    return;
}

BITMAPFILEHEADER hdr; // bitmap file-header

hdr.bfType = 0x4d42; // ('M' << 8) + 'B';

// Calculate the size of the entire file.
hdr.bfSize = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + pbih->biSize + pbih->biClrUsed * sizeof(RGBQUAD) + pbih->biSizeImage;
hdr.bfReserved1 = NULL;
hdr.bfReserved2 = NULL;

// Calculate the offset to the array of color indices.
hdr.bfOffBits = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + pbih->biSize + pbih->biClrUsed * sizeof(RGBQUAD);


const DWORD cb = pbih->biSizeImage; // incremental count of bytes


std::stringstream outputBitmap;

// Write the BITMAPFILEHEADER into the .BMP file.
outputBitmap.write( reinterpret_cast<LPSTR>(&hdr), sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER));

// Write the BITMAPINFOHEADER and RGBQUAD array into the file.
outputBitmap.write(reinterpret_cast<LPSTR>(pbih), sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + pbih->biClrUsed * sizeof(RGBQUAD));

// Write the array of color indices
outputBitmap.write(reinterpret_cast<LPSTR>(lpBits), cb);




// To test the whole thing
std::ofstream out("test.bmp", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
out << outputBitmap.str();
out.close();


// Cleanup
DeleteDC(hdcScr);
DeleteDC(hdcMem);
LocalFree(pbmi);
GlobalFree(lpBits);
DeleteObject(hbmScr);
```

Comment: Will the display DC, with a monitor that is to the left of origin, not require negative co-ordiates (negative x in your case)?

Comment: There must be a million screenshot questions on SO and yet they keep coming up.

Answer (score 7):

Monitors can have negative coordinates, so it's dangerous to assume that (0, 0) is the monitor's top left corner<sup>†</sup>. The real origin (x, y) is given by the system metrics `SM_XVIRTUALSCREEN` and `SM_YVIRTUALSCREEN`. Then all of your BLTs have to be updated to refer to the correct source location. This makes the first bit of the function:

```
int x = GetSystemMetrics(SM_XVIRTUALSCREEN);
int y = GetSystemMetrics(SM_YVIRTUALSCREEN);
int w = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN);
int h = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN);

BOOL ok = StretchBlt(hdcMem, 0, 0, w, h, hdcScr, x, y, w, h, SRCCOPY);
// And So On...
```

Alternatively, since these kind of questions get asked a lot, you can get the individual monitors using something similar to the following piece of not-quite-production-quality code:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using std::wcout;
using std::endl;

typedef struct tagMonData
{
    int current;
    MONITORINFOEXW* info;
} MonData;

BOOL EnumProc(HMONITOR hMonitor, HDC hdcMonitor, LPRECT lprcMonitor, LPARAM dwData)
{
    MonData* data = (MonData*)dwData;
    data->info[data->current].cbSize = sizeof(MONITORINFOEXW);
    return GetMonitorInfoW(hMonitor, &(data->info[data->current++]));
}

BOOL GetAllMonitorInfo(MonData* data)
{
    return EnumDisplayMonitors(NULL, NULL, (MONITORENUMPROC)(&EnumProc), (LPARAM)(data));
}

int main()
{
    int cMonitors = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CMONITORS);
    MonData data;
    data.current = 0;
    data.info = (MONITORINFOEXW*)calloc(cMonitors, sizeof(MONITORINFOEXW));

    if (!GetAllMonitorInfo(&data)) return 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < cMonitors; i++)
    {
        wcout << data.info[i].szDevice << "X: " << data.info[i].rcMonitor.left << " Y: " << data.info[i].rcMonitor.top << endl;
    }

    free(data.info);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that this will shortcut and leave incomplete information if the `GetMonitorInfoW` call fails for some reason.

---

*<sup>†</sup> Raymond Chen has written several articles about the complexities of the Windows coordinate system over at [The Old New Thing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/)*